# Can I trust elements from a new Array to equal to false?

Tags: javascript

In the browsers I tested, `var a = new Array(5);` will return an Array of 5 `undefined` elements. Since `undefined` equals to `false` I can consider my array to be initialized with `false` elements as long as I test them this way:

```
if (a[0]) console.log("the element is no longer falsy");
else a[0] = true;
```

Is it a safe way to initialize an `Array` with `false` values or is it just a hack that should be avoided?

EDIT: my goal is to have it initialized to falsy values as in my example. I want to make sure that `new Array()` is a trustworthy way to do so.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Your are not forced to initialize your array, you should have a specific reason to implement this.

Comment: I am trying to have an array initialized to falsy values so I can turn them to true later on. The only test I do on the values is `if (a[i])` so `undefined` is a good init value for me, as long as it the JS norm imposes this behavior on `new Array()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you initialize an array in Javascript it has no elements, i.e. nothing is present in any position unless you put something there. The only thing you have is `length` set to the number you specify.

When you access the element by reading it and nothing is there then you get `undefined` (as it happens when you acces a member of an object that doesn't exist).

Note however that an element that is not present at all is not exactly the same as an element that is set to `undefined`. For example:

```
var x = new Array(5);
console.log(x[2]);                 // ==> Output is "undefined"
console.log(x.indexOf(undefined)); // ==> Output is "-1" (not present)
x[2] = undefined;
console.log(x.indexOf(undefined)); // ==> Output now is "2"
```

If you only care about whether an element will be considered `true` when placed in an `if` then the array appears at a first sight to contain `undefined` that is `false` in that context.

Note however that even what is `false` or `true` is quite a subtle concept in Javascript, especially because of automatic conversions... for example

```
console.log([] ? 1 : 2);  // Output is "1", an empty array is "true"
console.log([] == false); // output is "true" (so it's also equal to false!)
```

Comment: so empty arrays are truthy `!![] //true` but also type coerce to `false`: `[] == false //true`? This is madness!

Comment: @FabrícioMatté: welcome to hell ]:-) ... the reason because this happens is somewhat subtle, and implies also that `[1] == 1`. The `==` operator in Javascript is basically useless... you should always use `===`.

Comment: So, I believe the toPrimitive of an array is to cast to string so `[1, 2] == '1,2' //true` right? Makes sense now as `false` would be an empty string then: `[] == '' //true`

Comment: @FabrícioMatté: exactly... only because of a special rule that says that the empty string can be *implicitly* converted to 0 and doesn't become `NaN` as it happens for other non-numeric strings. `parseInt("")` however returns `NaN`.

Comment: I'm aware of `'' == 0` and `parseInt("")` returns `NaN` but `NaN != NaN`, also `+''` returns `0`. Though, I wasn't aware that `[] == 0` too.

Answer (score 1):

The undefined value does not "equal" to `false`, it's just considered *falsey* when you test it like `if(undefined)`.

Whether it's safe or not, it really depends on the code you're using it on. If you want to check if value is really `false`, you should use strict equality and check `if(val === false)`, so you don't mistake it for any other falsey value.

You can also check the `typeof` the variable to make sure it's what you expect:

```
typeof false;      // "boolean"
typeof undefined   // "undefined"
```

Comment: Thanks. As I was saying "I can consider my array to be initialized with false elements as long as I test them this way: `if (a[O])...`" My concern is whether this test would work across (relevant) browsers or if only modern browser implement `new Array` like this

Answer (score 1):

You do not have to initialize your array for this to work.

```
var array = [];
console.log(array[0]); // undefined
console.log(!!array[0]); // false (undefined is _falsy_)
array.push("foo");
console.log(array[0]); // "foo"
console.log(!!array[0]); // true ("foo" is _truthy_).
array[1] = "bar";
console.log(array[1]); // "bar"
console.log(array.length); // 2
```

Comment: Very true: `var a = []; a[10]` will return undefined too.

Comment: Any performance difference as for memory management between the two (ie initializing with undefined and not initializing)? I believe the answer may depend on browsers...

Comment: `new Array(5);` is obviously less performant but the `length` property of the array is set to 5. When doing [], the size of the resulting array is 0 (try `[].length`)