# Coercing an array of length 1 to a number

Tags: javascript, arrays, optimization, obfuscation, type-coercion

I came across this in some obfuscated code:

```js
if (o > 0.5) {
```

I wrongly assumed that `o` was a number, leading me on a wild goose chase.  Turns out `o` is an array consisting of one value, a number.  Further experimentation shows that coercing an array of length 1 evaluates to the value at index 0.  For example:

```js
console.log(
  +[9] === 9 // true
);
```

Apparently, `o > 0.5` was shorthand for `o[0] > 0.5`.

I never knew this was possible before and I am having trouble finding anything written about it.  Can someone explain the ins and outs of array coercion?

Comment: Very interesting. But, I think, it can also be a shorthand for o>[0.5]. You may want to try [3,2,1]>[3,1,1]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I compare arrays in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16566772/how-do-i-compare-arrays-in-javascript)

Comment: If `a = [1]` then `a == 1` is true but `a === 1` is false...

Answer (score 1):

> Further experimentation shows that coercing an array of length 1 evaluates to the value at index 0

Not quite, coercing an array is equivalent to first calling `toString()` on the array, which returns the comma-concatenated list of values. If there's only one value then you get the string representation of that value. What happens after that follows the normal coercion rules when dealing with a string and another type.

Comment: The code snippet in my question seems to prove this can't be right.  It uses the strict equality sign `===` to compare `+[9]` with `9` and evaluates to `true`.  This would not be the case if either side were being coerced to a `String`.

Comment: @GirkovArpa `+` before a values is a shortcut way to coerce it to a number, so `[9] == "9"` is true and `+[9] == 9` is true