# Why [undefined] - 3 is -3 while undefined -3 is NaN in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have been studying JavaScript lately,
but I am not getting the [undefined] - x something is -x
but undefined - x is NaN...

```
console.log(undefined-3);  //NaN
console.log([undefined]-3); // -3
```

Comment: Because JavaScript is weird.

Comment: You could take a test like https://jsisweird.com/ and there are the answers that you are looking for. Like luk2302 said. JS is weird :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68632168/coercing-an-array-of-length-1-to-a-number

Comment: @luk2302 more weird than somebody trying to subtract an integer from an array? What would you consider a "non-weird" result of that? And how many would agree with you and wouldn't want a different result? Here are a few options to pick from: 1. apply the subtraction to each item in the array: `[3, 4, 5] - 3` -> `[0, 1, 2]` 2. reduce the length of the array: `[1, 2, 3, 4] - 3` -> `[1]`. 3. the result is `NaN` because the operation is nonsensical. 4. the result is `undefined` because the operation is nonsensical. 5. there is an error because the operation is nonsensical.

Comment: @VLAZ 5........

Answer (score 2):

**The explanation :** (Give your feedback)

Before the calculation, the compiler will try to convert **"undefined"** and **"[undefined]"** to a typeof **number**.

And the result is :

- undefined => NaN. (So, **"NaN - 3 = NaN"**)
- [] => 0. (**"0 - 3 = -3"**)

Check the list of JavaScript type Conversion [here](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_type_conversion.asp).